# VB6 printing bitmap or image on a POS Printer

Tags: image, printing, vb6, posprinter

I want to output a bitmap file to a POS printer using VB6.
The ESC/POS mode should be used.
Does the file need to be converted? If yes how?
Is there documentation or an example?
Thank you.

Printing and formatting text is no problem.
I just can't find any way to solve the problem.

Comment: That's going to be specific to the particular model and features of POS printer(s) you're working with.  Some printers can't print graphics.  Some printers can print a pre-loaded graphic.  Some printers can accept raster or bit image data and print it.  You need to refer to the documentation specific to your printer(s) for capabilities and how to accomplish your task (if it can be).

Comment: Thank you.
All POS printers we use support ESC/POS mode.

Comment: _All POS printers we use support ESC/POS mode_.  That's fine, but not every printer will support every command. For example, if a printer has a paper roll (it isn't an insert slip only printer) and is a tear-off style (it doesn't have a cutter mechanism), then that printer isn't going to support the ESC/POS cut command (GS V). You need to refer to the documentation for the printer(s) used to determine if those printer(s) support the various graphic commands and which of the graphic print abilities they have, if any.

Comment: Can you tell us the prnter name , model? Works only in ESC/POS mode or with ZPL also?

Comment: We use  ESC/POS mode. Model: EPSON TM-T 88 V.